# Proving the Fibonacci sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{F_{n+2}}{F_{n+1}}-\frac{F_{n+3}}{F_{n+2}}\right) = \frac{1}{\phi^2}$ and its friends

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers, constants

In this [article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciNumber.html), (eq.92) has,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{F_{n+1}F_{n+2}} = \frac{1}{\phi^2}\tag1$$

and I wondered if this could be generalized to the tribonacci numbers. It seems it can be. Given the *Fibonacci*, *tribonacci*, *tetranacci* (in general, the [*Fibonacci k-step numbers*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fibonaccin-StepNumber.html)) starting with $n=1$,

$$F_n = 1,1,2,3,5,8\dots$$

$$T_n = 1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24,\dots$$

$$U_n = 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 15, 29, \dots$$

and their *limiting ratios*, $x_k$, the root $x_k \to 2$ of,

$$(2-x)x^k = 1$$

with *Fibonacci constant* $x_2$, *tribonacci constant* $x_3$, etc, it can be empirically observed that,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{F_{n+2}}{F_{n+1}}-\frac{F_{n+3}}{F_{n+2}}\right) = \frac{1}{x_2^2}\tag2$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{T_{n+2}}{T_{n+1}}-\frac{T_{n+3}}{T_{n+2}}\right) = \frac{1}{x_3^3}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{U_{n+2}}{U_{n+1}}-\frac{U_{n+3}}{U_{n+2}}\right) = \frac{1}{x_4^4}$$

and so on. **Q:** How do we rigorously prove the observation indeed holds for all integer $k\geq2$?

***Edit***:

To address a comment that disappeared, to transform $(1)$ to $(2)$, we use a special case of *Catalan's identity*,

$$F_{n+2}^2-F_{n+1}F_{n+3} = (-1)^{n+1}$$

so,

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{F_{n+1}F_{n+2}} 
&= \frac{F_{n+2}^2-F_{n+1}F_{n+3}}{F_{n+1}F_{n+2}}\\
&= \frac{F_{n+2}}{F_{n+1}} - \frac{F_{n+3}}{F_{n+2}}
\end{aligned}$$

hence the alternating series $(1)$ is equal to $(2)$.

Comment: Umm.. either I'm looking at this incorrectly, or this telescopes particularly nicely.

Comment: @thkim1011: Feel free to be the first to answer.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start off with the case of the Fibonacci sequence. We have
$$\sum_{n = 1}^k \left( \frac{F_{n+2}}{F_{n+1}} -\frac{F_{n+3}}{F_{n+2}} \right) = \left(\frac{F_3}{F_2} - \frac{F_4}{F_3}\right) + \left(\frac{F_4}{F_3} - \frac{F_5}{F_4}\right) + \cdots + \left(\frac{F_{k+2}}{F_{k+1}}- \frac{F_{k+3}}{F_{k+2}}\right)\\
= \frac{F_3}{F_2} - \frac{F_{k+3}}{F_{k+2}} = 2 - \frac{F_{k+3}}{F_{k+2}}.$$
Setting the limit as $k$ approaches infinity, we get
$$2 - \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{F_{k+3}}{F_{k+2}} = 2- x = \frac{1}{x^2}$$
If you want more rigor, you can easily transform this into an induction argument.
Since $(2 - x)(x^2) = 1 \implies 2 - x = \frac{1}{x^2}$, the result follows. The proof generalizes really easily.

Comment: How was the $2$ from, $$2-\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{F_{k+1}}{F_k}$$ in the second line derived from the first line?

Comment: I edited the answer to make it clearer :)

Comment: Oh, should have seen that.  :)